# How to map file path from different folder location easily?

Tags: php, file, path, dictionary

how to map the path to the file easily?

```
public_html/api/function.php
<?php

function writetologfile($content)
{

    $filename = 'logfile/testing_randomstring.txt';

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) 
    {
        echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }
    fclose($handle);    
}

?>
```

the actual path of the text file is in `public_html/r/admin/logfile/testing_randomstring.txt`

so if I run the script at `public_html/folder1/folder2/addlog.php`, it won't be able to find the path to the `testing_randomstring.txt`

```
addlog.php
<?php

include("../../api/function.php");

writetologfile('hahaha');

?>
```

How I can able to easily point to this text file path, no matter where my php calling script is from.

I tried to change $filename = 'logfile/testing_randomstring.txt'; inside writetologfile function by enforcing it to absolute fix path, 
something like $filename='/r/admin/logfile/testing_randomstring.txt', 
but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a relative path, you could specify an absolute path. Assuming `public_html` is in your home directory, try this:

```
$filename = '/public_html/r/admin/logfile/testing_randomstring.txt';
fopen(getenv('HOME') . $filename, 'a');
```

This uses [`getenv`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) to read the contents of the environment variable `$HOME`.