# Mapping paths in PHP

Tags: php, html, navigation

I see a lot of threads here related to paths and includes in PHP, and that the prevailing wisdom is to use absolute paths in referencing resources. Something I'm confused about, however, is how to best map paths that correspond to navigation throughout the site. For instance, my site structure is as follows:

```
[root]
    main
        css
        js
        includes
    [section-1]
        index-1.php
        [section-1b]
            index-1b.php
    [section-2]
        index-2.php
```

In my primary navigation bar--for which I'm using an include-- in "index-1.php" I would use `<a href="../section-2/>` to link to another main section; however, within a sub-directory of one of those main sections, e.g. "index-1b.php", I would need to structure the link as `<a href="../../section-2/>` to reference the same path.

Rather than create separate header/navigation includes with corresponding paths, how might I reference these links in the primary site navigation in a singular, unified way? I see in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577257/how-to-map-file-path-from-different-folder-location-easily) the mention of using a variable to correspond to the path, which makes sense, however in the case I'm describing, I would need to include a reference to that variable for each navigation link-- I'm guessing there's probably a more efficient route?

Thanks for any guidance here.

Comment: Do you have any PHP file on root example maybe header.php or footer.php which is included in all the pages like its a master page.

Comment: Hi Mark-- the only file that currently exists in the root is the main (home) index.php file. I currently have the includes contained in an "includes" sub-folder of a "main" directory, as I have specified above.